# AngularJS ngRepeat - Use checkbox to filter list by single object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angular-filters

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16923/.

I'm trying to filter items in and out of a list where a value matches a particular property.

I have a 'shownEmployees' array, and when a 'Show Leavers?' checkbox is selected, I want the ng-repeat list to include objects where the 'leaver' property is 'Yes', otherwise, it should splice them. If the property is 'No', the object should always be included in the shownEmployees array.

I've done what should be more complex filters by multiple parameters using a $filter directive, but can't figure out a simpler way to filter only by the one property.

HTML:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="employee in allEmployees.shownEmployees | orderBy: sortEmployees | filter:searchEmployees">

<md-checkbox ng-change="allEmployees.showLeavers()" ng-model="allEmployees.filters.showLeavers">Show Leavers?</md-checkbox>
```

-

What I've tried to do in JS:

```
app.controller('allEmployeesController', function($scope, $http, $document) {

var _this = this;

$scope.sortEmployees = '+surname'

this.shownEmployees = $scope.employees;

this.filters = {
    showLeavers: false
}

console.log('Showing leavers?: ' + this.filters.showLeavers);

this.showLeavers = function() {

    console.log('Showing leavers?: ' + this.filters.showLeavers);

    angular.forEach($scope.employees, function(value, key) {
        if (value.leaver === 'Yes') {
            if (_this.filters.showLeavers) {
                _this.shownEmployees.push(value);
            } else {
                _this.shownEmployees.splice(value);
            }
        } 
        if (value.leaver === 'No') {
            _this.shownEmployees.push(value);
        }
    })

}
```

})

Comment: there are multiple issues with the code in your Fiddle.  Firstly, you can't declare `scope.showLeavers` as both a boolean for the `ng-repeat` and a function for the `ng-change` with the same name.  Secondly, your logic is wrong in the function, and is trying to push the items back into the source array (creating duplicates) instead of pushing into a new blank array.  And there isn't any reason to splice the unnecessary items, since those wouldn't be present in a blank array.

Answer (score 2):

Use custom filter:

```
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, showLeavers) {
    var filtered = [];

    var show = (showLeavers) ? 'Yes' : 'No'

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
       if(show == item.leaver) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }       
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

And:

```
 <li ng-repeat="employee in shownEmployees | myfilter:showLeavers">
```

---

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ost3zLLm/)</kbd>

Comment: He doesn't need to create a custom filter for this behavior. Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16925/ . The thing is, he need to ADD (show all) when the leaver check box is market as true...not filter by true/false. At least this was what I've understood.

Comment: This doesn't provide the functionality I stated above. Employees with 'leaver' property as 'No' need to be included all the time

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes in your code. Please try this below code and take a look and compare with your code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

 var scope = $scope;
  $scope.showLeaver=false;

 scope.employees  = [
   {
     name: 'Employee One',
      leaver: 'No'
    },
   {
     name: 'Employee Two',
      leaver: 'No'
    },
   {
     name: 'Employee Three',
      leaver: 'Yes'
    }
  ]
  
  $scope.shownEmployees = $scope.employees;
      $scope.showLeavers = function() {
  var isYes = $scope.showLeaver == true? 'Yes':'No';
 $scope.shownEmployees = $scope.employees.filter(function (el) { return el.leaver ==  isYes });

 }
$scope.showLeavers();

  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

  <input ng-click="showLeavers()" ng-model="showLeaver" value=""   type="checkbox" />
  
  <label for="showLeavers">Show Leavers?</label>
  
  <ul>
  
    <li ng-repeat="employee in shownEmployees">
      
      <p>Name: {{employee.name}}</p>
      
    </li>
    
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Very erratic code. Initially shows all employees, leaver or not, which it shouldn't, and when show leavers selected, shows non-leavers. Then  shows leavers when show leavers not selected. Also needs to show non-leavers all the time, as explained in question

Comment: @nick.cook Then just change this line as `var isYes = $scope.showLeaver == false? 'Yes':'No';` Could you please check it now?

Comment: Please read the question... Where 'leaver' is 'No', objects should always be included. Changing the above still won't fix that as I asked in the question

Answer (score 0):

you should change function js

```
 this.showLeavers = function(item) {
      this.shownEmployees = [];
            if(item){
            angular.forEach($scope.employees , function(list){
            if(list.leaver === 'Yes')
            this.shownEmployees.push(list);
          })
        }else{
            this.shownEmployees = angular.copy($scope.employees);
        }
    }
```

and html

```
<input ng-change="showLeavers(allEmployees.filters.showLeavers)" ng-model="allEmployees.filters.showLeavers" type="checkbox" id="showLeavers">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Fixed it using method below. When checkbox selected, shows leavers and non-leavers. When not selected, shows only non-leavers. No ng-hide expression, no use of controller. Method independent in $filter directive.

showLeaver expression passed in as parameter to showLeavers filter.

HTML:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy: sortEmployees | filter: searchEmployees | showLeavers:showLeaver">

<md-checkbox ng-model="showLeaver">Show Leavers?</md-checkbox>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('showLeavers', function() {
  return function (employees, showLeaver) {
    var matches = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {

      if (employees[i].leaver === 'No') {
        matches.push(employees[i]);
      }

      if (employees[i].leaver === 'Yes' && showLeaver) {
        matches.push(employees[i]);
      } else if (employees[i].leaver === 'Yes' && showLeaver == false) {
        matches.splice(employees[i]);
      }

    }

    return matches;

  }
})
```